# AngularJS Server-side rendering of ngRepeat directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

From a scenario where I have a server-side variable `modules` that contains an array of templates:

```
    modules = ["module1.html","module2.html","module3.html"];
```

Suppose that the server delivers the following:

*I'm using twig here for PHP but imagine what ever server-side code you might be using*

```
    {% for module in modules %}
        {% include ("modules/" ~ module) ignore missing %}
    {% endfor %}
```

This will give me the contents of `module1.html`, `module2.html` and `module3.html` concatenated.

The equivalent AngularJS code would be:

```
    <div 
        ng-repeat="module in modules track by $index" 
        ng-include="'modules/' + module">
    </div>
```

Now, what I want is having a server-side rendered version of this ngRepeat.

If I do this:

```
    {% for module in modules %}
        <div 
            ng-repeat="module in modules track by $index" 
            ng-include="'modules/' + module">

        {% include ("modules/" ~ module) ignore missing %}

        </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

Then I will have `modules.length * modules.length` modules on the page when Angular kicks in, which is not acceptable.

How can I have Angular **take over** that listing, and introduce the ngRepeat directive over it, without multiplying the results? In other words, how can I render an ngRepeat directive with server-side bootstrapped data and not relying on angular to do the compiling?

#### Update

I just found [a partial solution](http://sebgoo.blogspot.com/2013/05/angularjs-and-seo-pre-render-content-on.html) using templates:

```
    <div ng-include="'modules'">
        {% for module in modules %}
            {% include ("modules/" ~ module) ignore missing %}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="modules">
        <div 
            ng-repeat="module in modules track by $index" 
            ng-include="'modules/' + module">
        </div>
    </script>
```

Which kinda works, but I'm looking for different options.

Comment: Please let me know if it's unclear or there's information missing, thanks

Comment: I think your 'partial solution' is an excellent route to go, given that there are some things that are just too difficult to reconcile when trying to progressively enhance server-rendered content with client-executed script. I'll probably use this in a writing shortly. Kudos to you.

Answer (score 0):

try using this npm package, which will render any angular template:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-node-compile

```
var ngcompile = require('ng-node-compile');
var ngEnviorment = new ngcompile();
ngEnviorment.$compile("<div ng-repeat=\"n in [1,2,3,4,5]\">hello {{name}} {{n}}</div>")({ name: 'Jhon doe' });
```

Comment: If you recommend a library/module, it's customary to show how it can be applied.